# How do i globalize and manipulate a character array across functions

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Im trying to maintain the content of my multidimensional character array thru various access to function calls where it will be changed. How can i do that. Do i need to pass the array to the function? If so how do i do it. However i try I'm getting syntax errors. 
This is my function declaration

`void board(int,int,int);`

Do i need to add a reference to my multidimensional character array?

`char piece[3][3];`

When I call the function how do i pass it to the array?

`board(whichplayer,rownum,columnnum);`

In the function itself how do i add it and use it and declare it?

```
void board(int movesquare, int row, int column)
 {
  //...
 }
```

Comment: So to summarize, basically you want to know everything there is to know about this array?  ;)

Comment: do you want to maintain the characters constant? or do you want the function to change them?!!, what array and what function? movessquare or whichplayer?  clarify more...

Answer (score 1):

If your array is declared as global variable, then in every function in the same file where declared you don't have to pass array as function parameter.
**Example:**

```
char myArray[3][3];
void some_function(int var1,int var2);

int main(void)
{
  some_function(2,3);
.
.
.

}
void some_function(int var1, int var2)
{
extern int myArray[][3]; /* not necessary but just a reminder that 
                         you will use global variable in your function, 
                         size not necessary because this information in given
                          in  declaration on top */

myArray[var1][var2]=x; /* legal to modify global array */
.
.
.
}
```

If you don't want myArray to be global( and for many reasons many people will tell you don't) you have to pass that array as argument to your function.
**Example2:**

```
void some_function(char passed_array[][3],int size,int var1, int var2)
    /* array will be treated as pointer to 1d 3-elements array of chars,
    so empty first size   is unnecessary in first argument,
    but you will probably want to know what's the 
    true size so you pass it as 2nd argument to function */

int main(void)
{
  char myArray[3][3];
  some_function(myArray,3,1,1);
  .
  .
  .
}
void some_function(char passed_array[][3],int size, int var1, int var2)
{
  passed_array[var1][var2]=x; /* passed_array is a pointer so changes made here 
  will be visible as changes in myArray in main */
.
.
.
}
```